# Does RecordMyDesktop require a mic to record audio?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, microphone, recordmydesktop, audio-recording

Does RecordMyDesktop require a mic to record audio?
I just tried recording my desktop,  with audio, and the output file hasnt any sound. I was thinking it would take audio from the stream. ... Does record my desktop require a mic?

Is there desktop recording software that can record sounds without a microphone?

Comment: Their documentation says recordMyDesktop offers also the ability to
record audio
through ALSA, OSS or the JACK
audio server. I have used ALSA and JACK which are both supposed to work.